# How to graph 2^(x/8)-x? I just get a straight line

Tags: pgfplots

I am super new to LaTeX and have been trying to figure out how to graph the function 2^(x/8)-x.  When I use `pgfplots` the result is this:

[image: pgfplots]

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
        axis lines = middle]
        \addplot {(2)^(x/8)-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This differs from what [WolframAlpha shows](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E%28n%2F8%29+-+n+%3C+0) (inequality version which I am working towards):

[image: wfa]

My end goal would be to have a LaTeX graph that looks similar to the WolframAlpha graph (with the inequality shaded region), and I understand I need to modify the domain and some other styling, by main problem right now is I can't even get the equation to graph correctly.

What am I doing wrong?

And as an aside, it would be nice if I could somehow automate printing out the integer coordinates in a table where the values of x (or n) have a y that is less than 0.

Comment: Add `domain=-100:100` to the plot options: the default is `-5:5`.

Comment: Thank you.  That and samples were needed, and then narrowing down axis to the region I want to display.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `pgfplots` uses a default domain of -5,5 and in this domain the graph of your function seems a straight line. Supply a proper domain (and `samples` value):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        grid=both,
        axis lines = middle,domain=-70:70,ymin=-200,samples=100]
        \addplot[blue,no marks] {(2)^(x/8)-x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using the follwoing code you can get the x-coordinates of the points where the curve crosses the x-axis:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\xcoord[2][center]{{%
  % The actual point of interest
  \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\ix}{\iy}%
  % (0,0)
  \pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\ox}{\oy}
  % (1,1)
  \pgfplotspointaxisxy{1}{1}%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\ux}{\uy}
  \pgfmathparse{(\ix-\ox)/(\ux-\ox)}
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=both,
  axis lines = middle,
  domain=-70:70,
  ymin=-100,
  ymax=100,
  samples=100
]
  \addplot[blue,no marks,name path=curve] {(2)^(x/8)-x};
  \addplot[draw=none,name path=xaxis,forget plot] {0};
  \path[name intersections={of=curve and xaxis,by={a,b}}]
    node[circle,fill=red!70!black,inner sep=1.5pt,pin={[red!70!black]-85:\xcoord{a}}] at (a) {} 
    node[circle,fill=red!70!black,inner sep=1.5pt,pin={[red!70!black]130:\xcoord{b}}] at (b) {};
  \addplot[fill=none] fill between[
    of=curve and xaxis,
    split,
    every segment no 1/.style={fill,blue!20}];   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a loop you can get the desired table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{myfunc}{1}{%
  \pgfmathparse{2^(#1/8)-#1}%
}

\newcommand\xcoord[2][center]{{%
  % The actual point of interest
  \pgfpointanchor{#2}{#1}%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\ix}{\iy}%
  % (0,0)
  \pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\ox}{\oy}
  % (1,1)
  \pgfplotspointaxisxy{1}{1}%
  \pgfgetlastxy{\ux}{\uy}
  \pgfmathparse{(\ix-\ox)/(\ux-\ox)}
  \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  grid=both,
  axis lines = middle,
  domain=-70:70,
  ymin=-100,
  ymax=100,
  samples=100,
]
  \addplot[blue,no marks,name path=curve] {myfunc(x)};
  \addplot[draw=none,name path=xaxis,forget plot] {0};
  \path[name intersections={of=curve and xaxis,by={a,b}}]
    node[circle,fill=red!70!black,inner sep=1.5pt,pin={[red!70!black]-85:\xcoord{a}}] at (a) {}  
    node[circle,fill=red!70!black,inner sep=1.5pt,pin={[red!70!black]130:\xcoord{b}}] at (b) {};
  \addplot[fill=none] fill between[
    of=curve and xaxis,
    split,
    every segment no 1/.style={fill,blue!20}];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\par\noindent
\foreach \Value in {-50,...,50}
{%
   \pgfmathparse{myfunc(\Value)}%
   \ifdim\pgfmathresult pt <0pt\relax
  $(\Value,  \pgfmathparse{myfunc(\Value)}\pgfmathprintnumber[precision=2]{\pgfmathresult})$\par\noindent
  \fi
}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, this got me on the track I needed to be on.

Comment: Is it possible to show the node coordinates where it crosses the X axis without knowing the X value for which that happens?

Comment: @akevit Sure. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @akevit Answer updated again, including the table.

Comment: Wow thank you so much.  I was using Papeeria for this but doesn't look like it supports some of the packages being used, but I'll send them an email and work in an offline Latex environment.  Thanks again!